# Does a static value need to be in an SQL group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, vertica

Had a conceptual question while writing an SQL in Vertica.  Though this is a general conceptual SQL question.  Here is the code:

```
Select 'staticValue' as doesThisNeedToBeInMyGroupBy,
       dimension as measureName,
       Sum(measure) as measureValue
From Tables
Group by dimension
```

The aggregate results appear the same with or without `staticValue` in the group by.  Wondering the right way or best SQL practice.

Thank you for reading and sharing any questions or experience.

Comment: The static value does not need to be in the `group by`.  In fact, some databases (e.g., SQL Server) do not allow it.

Comment: Good call out. Each database behaves a little differently.  Seen strange and unexpected outputs from `MySQL` before

Answer (score 0):

In `vertica`, the static value is not needed.  Behavior varies depending on database.  Though for this case the static value is not needed in the group by.

H/t [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) for helpful commentary to confirm.